# Panel Default button property is not working?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i place one panel in that one textbox wiht multiline property to true and one button. when i place default button property of panel to button, but it is not working it the textboxe multy line property is the reason? help me,

Comment: What you mean by not working? If your focus is on the textbox, pressing enter, what should be your expected behavior? Move cursor to next line or trigger the button?

Comment: when we place textbox and button in a panel if we set the property default button to button contrl id, when we presee entered automatically button will fire - Anuraj try it once

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example, this might help you:

```
<div id="LoginForm">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnCustLogin">
          <h1>User Login</h1>
          <label>Email ID:</label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustEmailID" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:Button ID="btnCustLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnCustLogin_Click"/>
        </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Comment: Saurabh, actually my texbox is TextMode="MultiLine", if it is not textmode="MultiLine" it is working. but i want multiline for my textbox

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior

> Pressing the ENTER key with focus inside a multi-line textbox. In a
>   multi-line textbox, pressing the ENTER key should create a new line in
>   the textbox which is the expected behavior. In browsers where the
>   pressing the ENTER key inside a multi-line textbox triggers a post
>   back but you want the ENTER key to create a new line instead you can
>   attach a JavaScript function to the input control. The script should
>   capture the ENTER key and stop the post back. For example, you can use
>   the Attributes property collection to add client script for the
>   onKeyPress event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx